# Read two SQL using two different dataframe and compare the two resultant datasets

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe

Read two SQL(both  SQL query has 7 similar column structure) using two different data frame and compare the two resultant datasets whether they match.
I have tried with .equals operator but I got:

```
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

I am writing the code using Python Pandas. Let me know if something like that is possible, I am new to Python any help or advice would be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please add the whole code to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the (exact) [equality](https://www.w3resource.com/pandas/dataframe/dataframe-equals.php#:%7E:text=DataFrame%20%2D%20equals()%20function,same%20location%20are%20considered%20equal.) of a DataFrame like this:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({1: [20], 2: [30]})  # here would be your first sql-query

df2 = pd.DataFrame({1: [20], 2: [30]})  # here would be your second sql-query

df1.equals(df2)  # results in True/False
```